# Reviewboard RBTools: get files that have changed from different diff

Tags: python, python-2.x, review-board, rbtools

Let's say I have a review request which has 10 files 
From diff 1 and 2, I've only changed 1 file

```
client = RBClient()
root = client.get_root()

files = root.get_files(review_request_id=1, diff_revision=1)
files2 = root.get_files(review_request_id=1, diff_revision=2)
```

The above code shows the same number of files `len(files) == len(files2)`

What can i do to only get the files that have been modified in diff 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting files for each diff and compared the content

```
curFiles = root.get_files(review_request_id=1, diff_revision=2)
prevFiles = root.get_files(review_request_id=1, diff_revision=1)

for f in curFiles:
    #compare f.get_patched_file() vs corresponding f.get_patched_file()
```